# Sendmail dot-addressing

Tags: linux, sendmail, rhel5

I need to be able to route mail to user.@ to user@. I know I can do it easily with + addressing, but the business requirement is for dot-addressing. The virtusertable file can't handle it - using user* doesn't do anything for me. The  section is created dynamically by automated regression tests, so a static list in /etc/aliases won't cut it either. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your *sendmail.mc* file add the following lines:

```
LOCAL_RULE_0
R$+ . < @ $=w . > $*         $: $1 < @ $2 . > $3
```

Keep in mind that the left hand side of the rule is separated from the right hand side using tabs and not spaces. So do not copy-paste, type the rule. Next build *sendmail.cf* and restart sendmail according to your system's guidelines. For example in Debian and Ubuntu systems one can run `sendmailconfig`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the `sendmail.cf` file?

Comment: Yes, but you really want to avoid hacking / editing sendmail.cf directly.